# Matlab can't run on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, matlab

I have installed Matlab a long time ago and now when I am trying to run couldn't do it. More  deeply, I am trying Matlab as double clicking mouse on it's icon as well right click and run as administrator but unfortunately  It shows me matlab for a few seconds and disappeard suddenly. What is wrong?

Why can't run it?  Just note that after some trying, maybe matlab will run,but it takes to long time. So I think that it is has a some problem with it's compatibility, but I couldn't find reason and fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Try reinstalling Matlab from the original DVD.

You could also try running Matlab directly by clicking on its .exe:

For the 32-bit version of Windows:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB
```

For the 64-bit version of Windows:

```
C:\Program Files\MATLAB
```

Comment: I've run Matlab 2009-2011 on Win7 x64 without issue under admin and non-admin accounts.  Start with a reinstallation to solve your problem.